# Can't install apk in android x86

Tags: android, android-x86

I have android x86 dual booted with windows 8.1 on my machine.
It's android 6.0. And I'm trying to install a apk file in x86 and it gives me a 'Can't open file' error. I checked all apps in settings...there's no package installer app!
PS - this is my first question here..please pardon my English.

Comment: if the APK contains only ARM code it can't run on x86. which apk do you try to install?